# RSA From android to php server

Tags: java, php, android, rsa

So i try to make this:

1. Create to keys (pulic & private) on Android (ок)
2. Create to keys (pulic & private) on  PHP (ок)
3. Send both (for test) from Android to PHP(ок)
4. Code with public key string on Android (ок)
5. Decode string (step 5) on PHP side (fail)
6. Code & Decode string on PHP side (with keys from android works fine!)

   PHP

   ```
   $pub=$_POST['pub'];             
   $priv=$_POST['priv'];           
   $data=$_POST['data'];           
   $data2=$_POST['data2'];         

   $pubkey=base64_decode($pub);    
   $privkey=base64_decode($priv);  

   $data= base64_decode($data); 
   openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted2, $privkey);
   echo $decrypted2; //EMPTY!

   //BUT!
   openssl_public_encrypt("heddlo fd df d world 2", $crypted, $pubkey);
   $crypted=base64_encode($crypted);
   $crypted=base64_decode($crypted);
   openssl_private_decrypt($crypted, $decrypted, $privkey);
   echo $decrypted; // works fine!!
   ```

   Java Android

   ```
   //### Key pair

   String alias = "someTxt-RSA";

           KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA"); 
           KeyPairGenerator kpg2 = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");                 
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
           kpg.initialize(2048,new SecureRandom()); //new SecureRandom()
           KeyPair pair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

           privateKey=pair.getPrivate();
           publicKey=pair.getPublic();

           PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keyspec = new KCS8EncodedKeySpec(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
           PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keyspecpub = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());

           byte[] arrByte =pair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
           byte[] arrByte2 =pair.getPublic().getEncoded();
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                           sb.append("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"+" \n");
                           sb.append(Base64.encodeToString(arrByte, Base64.DEFAULT));
                           sb.append("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

           StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                           sb2.append("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"+" \n");
                           sb2.append(Base64.encodeToString(arrByte2, Base64.DEFAULT));
                           sb2.append("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
           String privKeyBase64=Base64.encodeToString(sb.toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
           String pubKeyBase64=Base64.encodeToString(sb2.toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);


   //### code string with public key JAVA

           byte[] encodedBytes = null;
           Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
           c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
           encodedBytes =theTestText.getBytes("UTF-8");
           encodedBytes = c.doFinal(encodedBytes);
           String  coded =Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

   //### sending to  PHP

   String urlString = "URL"; // URL to call
           String pub = pubKeyBase64; //data to post
           String priv = privKeyBase64; //data to post
           String data = params[0].getData("data"); //data to post
                   try {
                   String data2 =coded; //data to post
                   OutputStream out = null;   

                       URL url = new URL(urlString);

                       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(urlString);

                       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);                   
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pub", pub));
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("priv", priv));
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data2", data2));

                       postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                       HttpResponse responseHttp = httpclient.execute(postMethod);

                       return EntityUtils.toString(responseHttp.getEntity());
   ```

Comment: Hey@Mars basically both side padding need to same i mean if you are using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding in android side then you need to use same at PHP side otherwise it give error or not decode

Comment: `3. Send both (for test) from Android to PHP(ок)`. No. Not ok. You did not only send the keys but also leading and trailing text.

Comment: `4. Code with public key string on Android (ок)`. No. You did not encrypt anything. You did not use a key. You only base64 encoded the payload. Well one only.

Comment: `5. +Decode string (step 5) on PHP side (fail)`. The base64 decode should work. How do you know it fails? What fails? And which statement exactly?

Comment: `6. Code & Decode string on PHP side (with keys from android works fine!)` ?? What are you doing exactly? If 5 fails then how would you continue?

Comment: Thank you! I understand! I need the same padding (but on my PHP server works only OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA (i think it is constatnt for padding type). But i have no idea how to set it on Android...

Comment: @Dilip  On PHP i have only two paddings: OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING & OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING

If you know some paddings for Cipher that will works fine with PHP - o will be very happy))